# Angular Bootstrap Navbar With Dropdowns Routing

Tags: html, jquery, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm currently creating an Angular project with a Bootstrap Navbar.
The Navbar has dropdowns with dropdown items which routes the user to different pages.

I have installed Bootstrap, jQuery and Popper.

My issue is that when I click the dropdown or dropdown items ( they are <.a> tags ) my project does not route to the indicated page and nothing happens. The url also remains unchanged.

In the following example code I have one dropdown that when clicked or one of the dropdown items are clicked the user gets routed to the "inventory" page.

Here is my HTML code for the navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">

  <a [routerLink]="['/test']">
    <img class="img-responsive navLogo" src="assets/images/LogoNoBG.png" width="75" height="65">
  </a>

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">

      <!-- Inventory -->

      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" [routerLink]="['inventory']" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Inventory
        </a>

        <!-- Dropdown Items -->

        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['inventory']">Example 1</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['inventory']">Example 2</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['inventory']">Example 3</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['inventory']">Example 4</a>
        </div>
      </li>

    </ul>

  </div>

</nav>
```

I'm not sure why it is not working.
Any help would be appreciated.
If you know of any other way to do a navbar with dropdowns in Angular also please let me know.
Thank you!

Comment: I hope you figured out a good approach for fixing this. Could you please share? I'm building something similar.

Comment: @Nodira I posted an example of the code we ended up using. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the problem was that I forgot to add a / before my routes.

I haven't worked on the project for a while.

But here is an example of working code we ended up using:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
 
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
  
        <!-- Navbar Item One -->
  
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">

          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Navbar Item One
          </a>

          <!-- Dropdown Items -->
  
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/route1']">Dropdown Item One</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/route2']">Dropdown Item Two</a>
          </div>
        </li>
  
        <!-- Navbar Item Two -->
  
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">

            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Navbar Item Two
            </a>

            <!-- Dropdown Items -->
    
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/route1']">Dropdown Item One</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/route2']">Dropdown Item Two</a>
            </div>
          </li>

      </ul>
  
    </div>
  
  </nav>
```